# SQL statements in onOpen trigger in Apps Script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I have written a logic using Google Apps Script which will verify the logged in users email id with the one present in the database.If the email is present in database, populate the logged in user's email id in one of the cell.This should be done without manual intervention and onOpen event of spreadsheet and should also work if someone tries to make a copy of the same spreadsheet.

If method **does not contain SQL statements** then, onOpen() gets executed in both

1. in the original sheet
2. when someone makes copy of it,

If method **contains SQL statements** then, onOpen() gets executed **ONLY**

1. in the original sheet (will not be executed if someone or even I, myself make copy of
   it).

Please confirm,

1. if my understanding is correct and SQL statements does not work in
   onOpen() trigger when someone makes copy of the sheet.
2. What could be the alternative to implement this functionality that gets executed in original sheet and in the copy(made using option Make a Copy)

Answer (score 0):

Don't name it onOpen, use something else so it runs under your userId and not each user.
Doing that will break the copy since you will need to install the onOpenTrigger manually

Comment: I would like to run it for all the users who will make copy of my sheet. I tried giving it a different name and installing it under All Resources but observed that when a copy is made of the sheet, the trigger does not get copied to the new created copy sheet.

Comment: For such situation, I usually add some button to menu, like "Install Trigger" and mention to users that after creating a copy this has to be run. Once user runs it and gives appropriate permission, the script will work fine. There's no way to workaround scopes w/o user permission, cause that would break google app script security policy.